# MIPS difference in this instruction?

Tags: mips

Can someone explain what is the difference between:

```
lw $t5, $t3
```

and

```
lw $t5, ($t3)
```

and

```
lw $t5, 0($t3)
```

The 1st one and the 2nd one work as expected. But why the 3rd one is different from the 2nd one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your assembler is very forgiving, the first example is a syntax error:

```
lw $t5, $t3
```

Both `spim` and `mars` flag it. The `lw` instruction is "load from memory". If you wanted to set the contents of `$t5` from the contents of `$t3`, you'd want the `move` pseudo-op:

```
move $t5, $t3
```

which is shorthand for:

```
addu $t5, $t3, $zero
```

The correct usage of `lw` is:

```
lw <dest_reg>,<offset>(<source_reg>)
```

This takes the contents of the source register, adds the *signed* [16 bit] offset to produce a final address. It will fetch the 32 bit word from that address and place the fetched value into the destination register.

If `<offset>` is zero, it can be left off, so the following two are equivalent:

```
lw $t5, 0($t3)
lw $t5, ($t3)
```